# How can I see the buttons in the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently coding my first django website and I'm stuck with the navbar. Well, I've downloaded from bootstrap a navbar just like this one.[image]
However, when i run the server, the navbar looks like this.

[image]

I'd like to see the buttons in the navbar.

Here's the code:

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Does the menu toggle when you click it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows the `collapsed` layout of the bootstrap navbar, which does not include icons. I will post an answer to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As @Firoz Rangrez said before, from Boostrap you can download a lot of pre-styled object, it may possible that you downloaded a collapse navbar code. I very recommend you to use pure css and js (you write your own code and you understand better how it works), otherwise, you can have a look on this link *https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/*
Wish you find it usefull.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an answer to the question; OP specifically asked about a bootstrap navbar issue. Also, please consider posting a full code answer when replying to a question, look at my answer for an idea. You can also read here about best practices to answer questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used wrong code to create a navbar
The navbar-collapse class is used to create a nav with hamburger menu

refer this

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_brand&stacked=h

Remember to open in full page view

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand">CSMIT</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link history" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#History">History</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link req" href="#" name="request" data-toggle="modal"
                  value="Request">Request</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link req" href="#">Get All Students</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li>
              <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 p-2 m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i> Add student
              </button>
          </li>
          <li>
              <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 p-2 m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Notice" name="notice">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i> Add Notice
              </button>
          </li>
          <li>
              <button class="btn btn-danger my-2 my-sm-0 p-2 m-2"><i class="fas fa-unlock"></i> Logout</button>
              
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sharing an answer to the question; consider updating your answer with a full code solution that solves the OP's problem instead of just a link.

Comment: I have added the code you can refer that to add buttons. If you can have any query drop comment. I am happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

try this,

> one invalid html you closed `</nav>` two times in html.

> You can compare the code with **[`bootstrap nav`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)**

if you want to collapsible menu then add `navbar-expand-lg`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't see how a background-color results in an HTML element not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this most recent Bootstrap responsive navbar code if you want to see buttons in the desktop view. It will collapse still to a hamburger-icon-collapsed-menu without visible buttons in smaller screens (it shows buttons if you click on the hamburger icon toggle).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1">Reports</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/yLOGgzm